# Compiling Haskell (.hs) in windows to a exe

Tags: windows, haskell, compiler-construction

Is it possible to compile a set of `.hs` **haskell** files into a exe in windows? `.hs` -> `.exe`

Comment: GHC compiler will do that I believe. What have you installed?

Comment: im using `WinHugs` i think its a interpreter .. is compiling possible ?

Comment: @Sudantha Unfortunately you cannot compile to an exe in WinHugs. As you suggested, it is indeed an interpreter.

Comment: Sudantha: Please refrain from using text speak - that is ignorant and lazy English - remember - this is an English speaking forum, and international users are going to go "WTF" is that and what does it mean - some may not have the same English language skill as their native English speaking counterparts. Take this on board and remember it!

Comment: @t0mm13b we all are not from English speaking countries  !  .. we have difficulties

Comment: @Sudantha - well refrain from text speak and use proper English, we can help and will understand... but text speak belongs to handsets, not forums!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Absolutely. Install [the Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/), which gives you [GHC](http://haskell.org/ghc), a state-of-the-art compiler for Haskell.

By default it compiles to executables, and it works the same on Linux or Windows. E.g.

Given a file:

```
$ cat A.hs
main = print "hello, world"
```

Compile it with GHC:

```
$ ghc --make A.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( A.hs, A.o )
Linking A.exe ...
```

Which you can now run:

```
$ ./A.exe
"hello, world"
```

Note, this was under Cygwin. But the same holds for native Windows:

```
C:\temp>ghc --make A.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( A.hs, A.o )
Linking A.exe ...

C:\temp>A.exe
"hello, world"
```

Answer (score 6):

For people who never compiled anything at all, it also might be useful to know that "C:\temp>" in the example by Don Stewart points to the folder in which .hs should be. For example, if you have a folder under your user account, say "C:\Users\Username\Haskell\" in which you have your hello.hs file, you open command prompt by typing cmd, when it opens, you'll see "C:\Users\Username>". To compile you file type the following:

```
ghc Haskell\hello.hs
```

So the entire line should look like:

```
C:\Users\Username>ghc Haskell\hello.hs
```

Provided you have no any mistypes, you should be able to see the result in the same folder as you have your hello.hs file.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. [GHC](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/) can compile to C which can then be compiled to native machine code, or it can compile to LLVM.

Comment: And for unsupported hardware plattforms it can translate Haskell to C code.

Comment: Note that GHC by default uses its own native code generator, on Windows and Unixes.

Comment: Also, the C backend is deprecated since GHC 7.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply install the [Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/), including GHC and the IDE Leksah. Using this environment compilation becomes very easy and convenient.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows (without using Cygwin) there are two steps to creating the .exe file from the .hs file:

(1) You need to navigate in the command line terminal to the folder containing your .hs file.  To do so, you can either do:

- Go to Start >> Search programs and filles >> Type in "cmd" to launch the command line terminal, type "cd *PATH*" (where *PATH* is the correct file path to the folder where your .hs file is located), or
- You can manually navigate in your File Explorer to the specific folder where your .hs file is located, hold down the "Shift" key, right click within the folder, and select "open command window here." This will open up a command line terminal in the correct file location.

(2)  You need to compile the .hs file.  To do so, you can type after the prompt either:

- `ghc hello.hs` or
- `ghc --make hello`

Either option will produce a hello.exe executable file in the same folder as your hello.hs file.